# Null when var dumping for querying eloquent database?

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I'm trying to var_dump a table of users associated with a task, and im getting

NULL

Ultimately im trying to get a Task and associated it with the user, im not sure if im doing it correct.

This is using [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) in Slim.

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers;

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;
use App\Models\Task;

use App\Models\User;

class TodosController extends BaseController
{

    public function getTodos($request, $response, $args)
    {
        // $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY task");
        // $sth->execute();
        // $use = User::all();
        // below
        // $todos = DB::table('tasks')
   //             ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tasks.user_id')
   //             ->get();

        $todos = User::find(1)->tasks()->first();

        var_dump($todos);

        return $this->c->view->render($response, 'todos.twig', ['todos' => $todos]);

    }
```

Todos.twig

```
{% extends "templates/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>My Todos</h1>

<ol>
  {% for task in todos %}
        <div id="task{{task.id}}" class="myl" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li><h4>{{ task.task}}</h4></li>
        <small style="font-style:italic">{{task.created_at |date("m/d/Y")}}</small></br>
        <small style="font-style:italic">{{task.user.id}}</small></br>




    <button id="disappear" name="task" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask({{task.id}})">Delete</button>



        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</ol>
{% endblock %}
```

**Updated**

This is what my other files of code look like.

Not sure on why im getting the error

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];
    public $timestamps = [];


    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Task', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Task Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


// use Slim\Views\Twig as View;
// use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $fillable = ['task', 'user_id'];

    public $timestamps = [];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Updated

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that you are saying, `for the user with id = 1, get the first task of that user` ?... I assume the user with id = 1 exists and that user has at least ***ONE*** task....

Comment: @user919426 i don't know, all im trying to do is retrieve a user with the associate task.

Comment: Have you checked that the user exists in the database?... Are there also tasks associated with that user?

Comment: @user919426 according to sequal pro users exist and tasks exist however my sql doesnt show any sign of the tasks being linked to the users

Comment: @user919426 also when i do this `$todos = Task::where('id', 1)->first();` i get null to, but not for my users

Comment: Are there any tasks in the table? If there are, are there any where the user_id is 1?

Comment: @aynber there are tasks in the table yes, i put a user_id on them, i updated the post so you can see

Comment: The user_id is null in all of those rows, so they would never match to a user.

Comment: @aynber how would i match it to a user  ?

Comment: When you save the record, you need to save the user_id of the owner in the task record. You can do it manually, or create a function to assign tasks to users.

Comment: @aynber  create a function to assign tasks to users, how would i do that within slim ?

Comment: No idea about slim, but basically it's similar to the way you create users and tasks. You get a list of all tasks or tasks where the user_id is null, get a list of users, then say "this task belongs to this user." That's a functionality you're going to have to think about, design, and build yourself.